# $_SESSION NOT Working for some browser

Tags: php, session-variables

Is there a reason for that. If I go to my website with the Facebook browser, they do not load my session. Plus my friend is having the same problem with his browser (Google Chrome and Firefox). But for me and my 2 other friends that are working on the website + everywhere it work correctly. Except when I use the Facebook browser.

Thanks for helping me to understand this problem.

Comment: have you declared `session_start()`, frequent human error.

Comment: What do you mean by "Facebook browser"?

Comment: Facebook browser? Is there a browser named like that??

Comment: Yea the session is working for me. Facebook browser mean the mobile apps on the cellphone when you click on a click on a link it will open in the apps.

Comment: This is 2 picture to show the difference:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/1901340_854105731300215_3808072449663835976_n.jpg?oh=27c7b8142feb62f5a5aba160d95b9392&oe=54F53227&__gda__=1421724698_628d25fd4b4ae5d8cf676dde5a64e04f

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10702148_10204465112400317_4161542465418566758_n.jpg?oh=ff73cfde103b1c8caf764fd78de40017&oe=54AA4CA0&__gda__=1421498388_cf5a2d8f212638a75836353c8eeb4449

Comment: It's a local issue and not a server-side issue. Once PHP has done its job, it's up to the browser to say "Yeah I like this, here you go." or "Nah, I'll just give you trouble". Check to see if everyone's cookies are enabled. Browsing just ain't like it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I wasn't getting the error and Facebook was giving an error that I don't even use on this page and I just fixed what they wanted (Include) and it fixed the problem. I still doesn't know why I got this problem and how it could happen but at least now it's fixed.